# Explode non-nested list columns that contain numbers

Tags: python, json, pandas, flatten

I have a Python script which uses a function to flatten a JSON object:

```
from pandas import json_normalize

def flatten(nested_json, exclude=['']): 
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude: flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out

x = [{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "labelId" : [
        6422,3421
    ], 
    "levels" : [
        {
            "active" : "true", 
            "level" : 3, 
            "actions" : [
                {
                    "isActive" : "true"
                }]
        }]
}
,
{ 
    "_id" : 2, 
    "labelId" : [
        57,78
    ], 
    "levels" : [
        {
            "active" : "true", 
            "level" : 4, 
            "actions" : [
                {
                    "isActive" : "true"
                }]
        }]
}

]

flatJSON = [flatten(i) for i in x]
flatJSON = json_normalize(flatJSON )
print(flatJSON)
```

**Output:**

```
  _id  labelId_0  labelId_1 levels_0_active  levels_0_level levels_0_actions_0_isActive
0    1       6422       3421            true               3                        true
1    2         57         78            true               3                        true
```

So the problem I am having is that this function flattens everything down to level 0 including lists, meaning it will create tons of unnecessary columns.

Is there a way to amend the function so that it simply explodes a list if it just contains integers/numbers rather than flattening it out into separate columns?

**Desired Output:**

```
   _id  labelId_0   levels_0_active  levels_0_level levels_0_actions_0_isActive
0    1       6422              true               3                        true
1    1       3421              true               3                        true
2    2         57              true               4                        true
3    2         78              true               4                        true
```